# Pushing numbers onto an array in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, iterator

I'm trying to create a program outputting each number and whether it is divisible by numbers 2-9.  I'm doing this by iterating over 2-9 and pushing each number onto an array, however, an error shows up when compiling:

```
/Users/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX.rb:3: warning: already initialized constant ArrayOfMultiples
```

How do I remove this error?

Here is my code:

```
(1..200).each do |number|
    output_str = ""
    ArrayOfMultiples = Array.new

    (2..9).each do |multiple|
        if number%multiple == 0 
        ArrayOfMultiples.push(multiple)
        end
    end

    output_str = number.to_s + " is divisble by " + ArrayOfMultiples.join(", ")
    puts output_str     

end
```

Comment: `ArrayOfMultiples`, because it starts with a capital letter, is a constant. You can change the value of a constant, but Ruby gives you a warning when you do so.  You want to rename it as a variable and initialize it as follows: `array_of_multiples = []`, or `array_of_multiples = Array.new`. [Here](http://rubyrocksu.wordpress.com/naming-convention/) is a description of Ruby's naming conventions.

Answer (score 2):

Start your variable with lower case, otherwise it is considered a constant. If you reinitialize a constant, you get that warning.

```
arrayOfMultiples
```

A simple program like the following can demonstrate this behaviour:

```
A = 1
A = 2
```

When you run the above script, it says:

```
test.rb:2: warning: already initialized constant A
test.rb:1: warning: previous definition of A was here
```

Comment: Don't just start variables with lower-case. Variables in Ruby are written using snake_case, not camelCase. It's_a_readablity_thing NotJustAStylisticChoice.

Answer (score 0):

You could also make this a lot simpler:

```
(1..200).each do |x|
  divisible_by = (2..9).select {|y| x%y==0}
  puts "#{x}: #{divisible_by.join(", ")}"
end
```